What does the SST field represent in the GFS forecast/ analysis?
What does the SST field represent in the GFS forecast/ analysis? For example, in the ERA5 reanalysis product, the SST is a foundation SST taken from the OSTIA. Similarly, what is the SST in GFS? Is it a foundation SST, skin SST, bulk SST, or an OI (Optimally Interpolated) SST?
